# gunicorn and websockets

Tags: python, websocket, gevent, gunicorn

I'm trying to get http://www.gelens.org/code/gevent-websocket/ running and keep getting the following error.

```
socket_id=1 already closed.
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/walt/virtualenv/ws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 571, in handle
    handler.handle()
  File "/home/walt/virtualenv/ws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 180, in handle
    result = self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/walt/virtualenv/ws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 314, in handle_one_request
    self.handle_one_response()
  File "/home/walt/virtualenv/ws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geventwebsocket/handler.py", line 26, in handle_one_response
    return self._handle_websocket()
  File "/home/walt/virtualenv/ws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geventwebsocket/handler.py", line 50, in _handle_websocket
    self.log_request()
  File "/home/walt/virtualenv/ws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 394, in log_request
    log.write(self.format_request() + '\n')
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I'm running python 2.7.2 on Mint Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this same bug with gevent-websocket 0.3.4 and gevent 0.13.6 when running the `gunicorn  -k "geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker" example:app` example.

The problem comes from a mismatch of expectations between gevent and gunicorn. Gevent's pywsgi module expects a logger object which implements a `write` method, like file objects, stdout, etc. Gunicorn, however, passes in an object which has [Logger](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logger-objects) methods (debug, info, error, critical, warning, etc).

The problem code in pywsgi:

```
def log_request(self):
    log = self.server.log
    if log:
        log.write(self.format_request() + '\n')
```

To fix this for myself, I hacked up the lines in a fork of gevent and changed them to the following:

```
def log_request(self):
    log = self.server.log
    if log:
        if hasattr(log, "info"):
            log.info(self.format_request() + '\n')
        else:
            log.write(self.format_request() + '\n')
```

Comment: Offending code: https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/5dca6e927bc4/gevent/pywsgi.py#cl-421

Answer (score 8):

used @bkad's code and added to main main app file

```
def log_request(self):
    log = self.server.log
    if log:
        if hasattr(log, "info"):
            log.info(self.format_request() + '\n')
        else:
            log.write(self.format_request() + '\n')

import gevent
gevent.pywsgi.WSGIHandler.log_request = log_request
```

to heder so that I wouldn't have to modify 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the latest versions of gevent and gevent-websocket on PyPi.

Comment: I installed with pip install gevent.

Comment: I'm using gevent 1.0dev latest from github and the above fix works for me.